# Java abstract method extend class

Tags: java

I need to create an abstract method that specifies an argument that accepts any child object of a specific class.

```
public abstract int insert(<? extends DBTable> object) throws SQLException;
```

I get the error that says "Abstract methods do not specify a body".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `DBTable` as argument.

Comment: hmm.. that works. for some reason i thought it wouldnt so i havent tried it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a generic method it have to look like:

```
public abstract <T extends DBTable> int insert(T object) throws SQLException;
```